# Can I concatenate environment variables in apache config?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, environment-variables, concatenation, setenv

I have two environment variables in apache config, I want to concatenate them into one new environment variable. Is this possible?

I realise this doesn't work, but it demonstrates the sort of thing I'm after:

```
SetEnv one foo
SetEnv two bar
SetEnv three one+two
```

...and then 'three' would have the value "foobar"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) regular expression with two wildcard backreferences to access the environment variables and concatenate the strings:

```
#This will be true for any user agent
RewriteCond  %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}  ^.*

#Replace / with / and set the new environment variable
RewriteRule  /(%{ENV:one})*(%{ENV:two})* / [E=three:$1$2]
```

Comment: Thanks. I just wish I could remember why I wanted to know that, now! :)