# Apache htaccess SetEnv: how concatenate environment variable in htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess, environment-variables

I want set some environment variable like this, eg.:

```
SetEnv SpecialPath "%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/dir/"
```

but if i print `SpecialPath` in path PHP, eg.:

```
$_SERVER['SpecialPath'];
```

the output is

```
%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/dir/
```

the expected output is:

```
/var/www/dir/
```

the question is: how concatenate environment variable in htaccess?

env_module is enabled

Comment: May be the `DOCUMENT_ROOT` is `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`

Comment: also you can try with `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']`.

Comment: @FrayneKonok the question is: how concatenate environment variable in htaccess...

Comment: Did you try this?? `SetEnv SpecialPath $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/dir/"`

Comment: @FrayneKonok yes... not work... same problem.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17550223/set-an-environment-variable-in-htaccess-and-retrieve-it-in-php

Comment: @FrayneKonok env_module is already enabled

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112605/discussion-between-frayne-konok-and-simone-nigro).

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/11270519/2729362

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}` variable is part of `mod-rewrite` so
You can set env for a document root using `SETenv` directive, try this `mod-rewrite` based example :

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteRule ^ - [E=SpecialPath:%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/dir/,L]
```